# Android How to view doc from sdcard in gallary?

Tags: android, search, gallery, document, sd-card

I have app in which user can search image,audio,video,doc file from sdcard and choose 1 file for upload it on server. 
Using Below code I can open the gallery and select image,audio,video But I have not idea that how to search doc from gallery.

Here is my code.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    //intent.setType("video/*");
    //intent.setType("audio/*");
    //intent.setType("image/*");
    //**What I have to do for view document[.pdf/text/doc] file**
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), REQUEST_CODE);
```

Does anyone have any idea how this can be achieved? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try this library **aFileChooser**
 its working fine

pls see this [link](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help you to open a doc

```
public void openDOC(String name) {


        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                + bmodel.getUserMasterBO().getUserid() + "/" + name);
        if (file.exists()) {
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/msword");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No Application Available to View DOC",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I want to view all file and than after I will select single file  form list. I do not want to open the doc. I need just a path so i can upload it on server.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
File docfolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                + "Documents/");
File docList[] = docfolder.listFiles();
for(int i=0;i<docList.length;i++)
{   
        if (docList[i].exists()) {
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(docList[i]);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/msword");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            try {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
             catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

            }
        }
}
```